# Website bookmarks as a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, links, bookmark

### Let me first explain what I am wanting to do...

I am wanting to add all my hundreds of website bookmarks that I have now in my browser, into wordpress for the following reasons.

- Can search my bookmarks by category
- Can search my bookmarks by tags
- Can search my bookmarks by description and/or name
- Can access my bookmarks from anywhere
- Can add a description to all my bookmarks
- Can add a screenshot image if I choose to (least important idea)
- Will have a custom template for viewing the bookmarks which will look different from a regular blog post/list

### And what I have done so far...

- Created a new post type **"Website Bookmarks"** with the code below

functions.php

```
<?php
/*
*  Add custom post type
*  name: website_bookmarks
*/

function bookmark_post_type()
{
    // Set some labels for our bookmarks post type
    $bookmark_labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Website Bookmark', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Websiteite Bookmark', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Websiteite Bookmark'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Website Bookmark'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Website Bookmark'),
        'new_item' => __('New Website Bookmark'),
        'all_items' => __('All Website Bookmarks'),
        'view_item' => __('View Website Bookmark'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Website Bookmarks'),'not_found' => __('No website Bookmarks found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Website Bookmarks found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Website Bookmarks'
        );

    $bookmark_args = array(
        'labels' => $bookmark_labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'bookmark',
            'with_front' => false),
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag', 'category'),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'can_export' => true,
        'supports' => array(
            'post-thumbnails',
            'thumbnail',
            'excerpt',
            'custom-fields',
            'editor',
            'title'
        )
    );
    
    register_post_type('website_bookmarks', $bookmark_args);
}

add_action('init', 'bookmark_post_type');
```

---

### And then what I need help/ideas with...

This gives me a custom post type, so I can add my bookmarks as a post, and search them and all that good stuff, also lets me easily keep them out of my main blog loop, so I can keep them more private if I choose to.  Also let's me easily create a template page just for the bookmarks.

### Questions

1. I would really like to be able to tag my bookmarks, many bookmarks will have more then 1 tag, example a site about PHP and MySQL and javascript, would be tagged with all 3 of those terms/tags.  I know wordpress has tags built in already and I utilize it a lot on my current blog posts, should I add a **NEW taxonomy** ie. **"bookmark_tags"** because when a user views a tag page right now, it shows all my blog posts for that tag and I do not want a PHP tag page to show all my post's tageed with PHP and all my bookmarks tagged with PHP on the same page, so is the best method to create a new taxonomy called bookmark_tags?
2. Same exact question as question number one (1), except in regards to **Categories** instead of **tags**?
3. Any other Ideas or suggestions to improve my bookmarks section?

---

### Thank you for any help

Comment: Do you've found any plugins for importing bookmarks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a clean way to accomplish what you need.

- Register custom post types (sans post_tags and categories)
- Register taxonomies specific to your bookmarks
- Create a post meta box for the bookmark options (sample included). You could add a nofollow checkbox option to the meta box.
- Save post meta

Here's the whole shabang.

```
add_action('init', 'bookmark_post_type');
function bookmark_post_type()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Bookmark', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Bookmark', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => __('Add New'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Bookmark'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Bookmark'),
        'new_item' => __('New Bookmark'),
        'all_items' => __('All Bookmarks'),
        'view_item' => __('View Bookmark'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Bookmarks'),'not_found' => __('No website Bookmarks found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Bookmarks found in Trash'),
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => 'Bookmarks'
        );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'bookmark',
            'with_front' => false),
        //'taxonomies' => array('post_tag', 'category'),
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'can_export' => true,
        'supports' => array(
            'post-thumbnails',
            'thumbnail',
            'editor',
            'title'
        )
    );

    register_post_type('bookmarks', $args);

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Bookmark Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Categories' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Categories' ),
        'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Category' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Category:' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Category' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Category' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Category' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Genre Category' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Bookmark Categories' ),
    );  

    register_taxonomy('bookmark_categories',array('bookmarks'), array(
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'labels' => $labels,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => true,
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'bookmarks_categories' ),
    ));

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Bookmark Tags', 'taxonomy general name' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Tag', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
        'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Tags' ),
        'popular_items' => __( 'Popular Tags' ),
        'all_items' => __( 'All Tags' ),
        'parent_item' => null,
        'parent_item_colon' => null,
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Tag' ), 
        'update_item' => __( 'Update Tag' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Tag' ),
        'new_item_name' => __( 'New Tag Name' ),
        'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate tags with commas' ),
        'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove tags' ),
        'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used tags' ),
        'menu_name' => __( 'Bookmark Tags' ),
      ); 

    register_taxonomy('bookmark_tags','bookmarks',array(
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'labels' => $labels,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'bookmark_tags' ),
    ));

}

//Create meta box
add_action('admin_init', 'bookmark_meta_boxes');
function bookmark_meta_boxes(){
    add_meta_box('bookmarks-meta', __('Bookmark Options'), 'bookmark_options', 'bookmarks', 'normal', 'high');
}

//Meta box form data
function bookmark_options(){
    global $post;
    $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'bookmark-url', true);

    echo "
    <div>
        <label for='bookmark-url'>URL</label>
        <input style='width:100%; padding:4px;' type='text' name='bookmark-url' value='$url' />
    </div>
    ";
}

//Save the form data
add_action('save_post', 'bookmark_save');
function bookmark_save($post_ID){
    //Do nonce checking here
    if('bookmarks' === $_REQUEST['post_type']){
        update_post_meta($post_ID, 'bookmark-url', esc_html($_REQUEST['bookmark-url']));
    }
}
```

To remove the bookmarks from the main loop, add this above the loop code:

```
query_posts('post_type=post');
```

If you want to control the archives and single contexts for your CPT, you will need to add two files called archive-bookmarks.php and single-bookmarks.php

By keeping 'publicly_queryable' as true in your post type, it allows searching of your bookmark posts.

You can use the_post_thumbnail function for your screenshot image.

I would use the content/editor area for your bookmark description.

Comment: thanks this is exactly what I ended up doing last night with 1 exception, I used `$custom = get_post_custom($post->ID);`  
    `$website_url = $custom["website_url"][0];` instead of what you have above `$url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'bookmark-url', true);`  is there any difference between two?  I am choosing your answer as well, thank you

Comment: @jasondavis `get_post_custom()` returns array of all custom fields for posts, while `get_post_meta()` returns custom field with the specific key

Comment: @jasondavis You can access the post meta however you choose. If you have one custom field, use get_post_meta, if you are storing more, use get_post_custom. :) Thanks Jason!

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling that people are afraid of custom taxonomies which is a shame,

from the codex:

> since version 2.3 of WordPress you've been able to create your own
>   custom taxonomies, but these have been a rarely used feature of
>   WordPress until Version 2.9.

For Both Bookmark **tags** and **categories** you should use **custom taxonomies**, it will make your search queries a lot easier and wont effect the rest of the site(post tags and categories).

And its free :)