# Any way to assign Post Categories and Tags to Links?

Tags: categories, taxonomy, tags, links

I would like to assign post categories and post tags to the links in my 'Links' section, and (ideally) remove the link categories feature since it would be redundant.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean you would like your permalink structure to be something like `root/category-name/tag-name/post-name`

Comment: No, I'm referring to the Links section in WordPress (a.k.a. the "blog roll"). Normally, you can categorize your links using link categories; I want to use post categories and tags instead.

Comment: It's impossible to do without "magic".

Comment: @Eugene: It's not "magic", it's just PHP. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use custom post types for links. You can do anything with CPTs that you can do with the old blog roll … and much more.

See also:

- [How to do a custom bookmarks post type?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/29375/73)
- [Website bookmarks as a custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/29236/73)
- [Aaron Parecki: Personal Bookmarks](http://aaronparecki.com/Wordpress)
- [Mark Wilkinson: WordPress Press This With Custom Post Types](http://markwilkinson.me/2011/08/wordpress-press-this-with-custom-post-types/)

Comment: Not an ideal solution, since I would basically need to rewrite the add/edit post templates for this custom post type to make it look and work like the 'Links' section. There must be a way to hook into the core and replace 'link_category' with 'category' as the link taxonomy...